# how i am get current time in PST in php and javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

how i am get current time in PST in php and javascript ?

Comment: PST? is it Pakistan Standard Time?

Comment: @Awais Qarni I guessed Pacific Standard Time.

Comment: @Awais: It is Pacific Standard Time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the PHP part, first, create a [**`DateTime`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object, that will contain the current time :

```
$date = new DateTime();
var_dump($date);
```

which gives :

```
object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '2011-03-04 08:00:56' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
```

And, then, set it's timezone to the one you want :

```
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('PST'));
var_dump($date);
```

Which gets you :

```
object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '2011-03-03 23:00:56' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'America/Los_Angeles' (length=19)
```

Answer (score 1):

In php you can get the current time of any location but for that you neeed to set the default time zone.

Here is the following code

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$current_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo $current_time;
```

Answer (score -2):

in **PHP**

change [timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

in **JS**

this [article](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/6016329) helps u

Comment: You should try to include relevant information from the linked pages.